# Is $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)=C_{p}^{\infty}(M)$ as sets and $C_{p}^{\infty}(M)\cap C_{q}^{\infty}(M)=\emptyset$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand germs of functions at p.

What I am not understanding is why or if it is $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)=C_{p}^{\infty}(M)$ as sets
(p.49 [https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~tkemp/251/250-251.Notes.pdf](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Etkemp/251/250-251.Notes.pdf)) or if it is actually $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)\simeq C_{p}^{\infty}(M)$ as sets.

To my understanding the construction of $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)$ starts with smooth functions on $U$ open, whereas $C_{p}^{\infty}(M)$ starts with smooth functions on all of M. Smooth functions on U can be extended using a bump functions. Therefore I see that one could identify smooth functions on U with a smooth function on M. This is what is done here I think:

https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/germs-of-functions/

Furthermore I am wondering if $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)\cap C_{q}^{\infty}(M)=\emptyset$ and thus tangent spaces defined as subspaces of ${C_{p}^{\infty}(M)}^{*}$ are disjoint. In Tu's book Smooth manifolds the tangent bundle is not directly defined as a disjoint union.Therefore I wonder if "being disjoint" is "build into" the definition using germs of functions.

Many thanks in advance